# Styling List Buttons

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink, html-lists

Using a list, I want to create a list of links as in the image

[image: HTML List with CSS background images]

```
<div id="toolbarbottom" class="toolbar" style="position: fixed; clear: both; overflow: visible; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%;">
     <ul>
         <li id="active"><span><a id="current" href="#add" class="button">News</a></span></li>
         <li><span> <a href="#Updates" class="button">Updates</a></span> </li>
         <li><span><a href="#Contact" class="button">Contact Us</a></span></li>
         <li><span><a href="#Website" class="button">Website</a> </span></li>
         <li><span><a href="#Refresh" id="#Refresh" class="button">Refresh</a></span> </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

I am kind of stuck on the CSS (button) and probably the spacing between the list elements.  to make the list appear in this form. Anyone with an idea of how I can tackle this please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

or another way is to use floats, and make the `ul` `display: inline-block` to contain the floated `li`'s

you need to slightly change the HTML so the `span` is inside the `a` - this is so you can hide the spanned text, but keep the image background and clickable area for the `a` elements, also I'd give each link a unique reference (class or ID) so the backgrounds can be applied separately.

example HTML:

```
<div id="toolbarbottom" class="toolbar" style="position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%;">
     <ul>
         <li class="active"><a href="#add" id="madd"><span>News</span></a></li>
         <li><a href="#Updates" id="mupdates"><span> Updates</span></a></li>
         <li><a href="#Contact" id="mcontact"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
         <li><a href="#Website" id="mwebsite"><span>Website </span></a></li>
         <li><a href="#Refresh" id="mrefresh"><span>Refresh</span></a> </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

you can then put the whole background on the ul and put the individual images on each link.

```
#toolbarbottom ul {
   list-style: none; 
   margin: 0; 
   padding: 0; 
   display: inline-block; 
   width: 100%; 
   background: #ff0;
}

#toolbarbottom li {
   float: left; 
   width: 80px; 
   height: 80px; 
   border: 1px solid #000; /* not required, just to show where individual links are */
} 

#toolbarbottom li a { /* make link fill the li element */
   display: block; 
   height: 80px; 
}

#toolbarbottom li span { /* hide the text */
   position: absolute;
   clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
   clip: rect (1px 1px 1px 1px);
}

/* couple examples of where to put individual backgrounds */   
#toolbarbottom #mupdates {background: #dad;}
#toolbarbottom #mcontact {background: #0f0;}
```

Comment: I applied the solution you have above, and I see the border. How do I align my image so it appears as if it is exactly in the center of each list element and reduce the click area to just that image area if I move the span inside of the click? Essentially my span was meant to enclose the click-able area, and I had the idea of working on the margin/padding properties to shrink it to exactly the size of my final image.

Comment: center the image with the `background-position: 50% 50%` or `center center`. reduce the clickable area by margining the `a` - so if the `li` is 80px x 80px like in my example the `a` might be  `display: block; height: 40px; margin: 20px;` then the `a` is only clickable on the 40px square area but is margined by 20px on each side to make it fill the 80px space

Answer (score 2):

You should first set up your css as an external style sheet rather than hard code it into your html. (See http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/styles.html for more on this). To add spacing between the li elements you can use the css cascade to add some bottom padding as follows:

```
#toolbarbottom ul li {
    padding-bottom:4px;
}
```

To make the list appear inline you would use:

```
#toolbarbottom ul{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Those button look like images, so to achieve that you'd just include them within each li element:

```
<li><a href="example.com"><img src="/path/to/image.jpg"></a></li>
```

Comment: @Soumyah92 true enough, but in this case for something so simple they have a very simple and easy to understand tutorial on external vs internal stylesheets. Feel free to post a link to a better tutorial if you have one :).

Answer (score 2):

***fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YaS9J/***

**css**

```
#toolbarbottom li {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0 10px;  
}

/* if you have one */
#toolbarbottom li img {
    display:block;   
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your comment. That was what I needed in addition to what I already got.